# Closing a substage

Tags: javafx-2

What I'm trying to do I think is exactly what Meg is talking about here: [JavaFX2 : Closing a stage (substage) from within itself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11468800/javafx2-closing-a-stage-substage-from-within-itself)

When I try to implement JewelSea's answer I get the "nonstatic method getSource() cannot be referenced from a static context."

So I have my secondary window (scene) created in Scene Builder with a simple controller class that has basically one function: tie the button to a close() event handler. Here's the code I have:

```
public class ProductNotFoundController
    implements Initializable {

    @FXML //  fx:id="closeButton"
    private Button closeButton; // Value injected by FXMLLoader


    @Override // This method is called by the FXMLLoader when initialization is complete
    public void initialize(URL fxmlFileLocation, ResourceBundle resources) {

        closeButton.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent> () {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent t) {
//                ProductNotFound.avisoClose();
                Node source;
                source = (Node) ActionEvent.getSource();
                Stage stage = (Stage) source.getScene().getWindow();
                stage.close();
            }
        });

    }

}
```

Can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong? And/or where should I put the close() method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace `ActionEvent` by `t`, [getSource](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/EventObject.html#getSource%28%29) is a non-static method.
jewelsea was using `actionEvent` the instance of the `ActionEvent` class.