# How do I close a sub-stage with a menu function in JavaFX/FXML/Java8?

Tags: javafx, fxml, java-8

I'm trying to do something similar to what the person was asking for here:  [Closing a substage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16451573/closing-a-substage)

except that instead of clicking a button, I'm doing this with a menu item and "onAction" call.

The window I'm trying to close is a sub-window.  My main FXML has a menuitem that when pressed, opens the window. Then the second.fxml has a menu item to close the window. The second.fxml has it's own controller ("FXMLSecondController.java")... but the stage was opened in the "FXMLPrimaryController.java".

My FXML menu item looks like this:

```
<MenuItem text="Close" onAction="#closeThisWindow" />
```

Then in FXMLSecondController.java I have:

```
@FXML
private void closeThisWindow(ActionEvent event) {
    if (closeWindowDialog()) {
        //close the window

        new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            @Override public void handle(ActionEvent aE){

               Node source1;
                source1 = (Node) aE.getSource();
                Stage stage = (Stage) source1.getScene().getWindow();
                stage.close(); 
            }
        };
    } else {

    }
}
```

(Note that "closeWindowDialog()" is a function that opens up a Yes/No dialog box and returns true/false)

I can't seem to access the stage from which I'm calling this menu item from...

PS. I'm working with JavaFX/Java 8 and NetBeans 8. No Scene Builder.

ANSWER:

Found the answer here:
[Unable to get Scene from MenuItem in JavaFX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20594392/unable-to-get-scene-from-menuitem-in-javafx) That was my problem.

Comment: Yes, I added it to the question. If I could close the question with the response "Answer found" I would.

Comment: You can answer your own question, but you will have to wait for sometime before you can answer your own question ! :D

Comment: Just wondering as you are using Java 8; Why don't you implement the `handle()` method as a lambda expression, if you are using Java 8 anyway?

Comment: I haven't started the mastery of lambda expressions yet... it's on the to do list!