# How to call default close operation of a stage in javafx?

Tags: java, javafx, exit

I wrote the defaultCloseOperation function of the primaryStage, but I have an exit button too and I want to run that defaultCloseOperation.
I tried to call the close() and the hide() methods of the stage but it exit immediately without calling my defaultCloseOperation function, but I need to call it because I need to release all the resources from the server side when I close the client.

Answer (score 4):

Do not do this on a closing operation of a `Stage`.

This is what the [`Application.stop`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/application/Application.html#stop--) method should be used for.

```
@Override
public void stop() throws Exception {
    // TODO: release resources here
}
```

---

If there are resources used for one of multiple windows however, you should use an event handler for the `onHidden` event - no need to extend `Stage`:

```
stage.setOnHidden(event -> {
    // TODO: release resources here
});
```

Answer (score 1):

you can see it:

```
stage.setOnCloseRequest(new EventHandler<WindowEvent>() {
    @Override public void handle(WindowEvent t) {
        System.out.println("CLOSING");
    }
});
```

and here:

```
new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
  @Override public void handle(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
    // take some action
    ...
    // close the dialog.
    Node  source = (Node)  actionEvent.getSource(); 
    Stage stage  = (Stage) source.getScene().getWindow();
    stage.close();
  }
}
```

more of explanation you can read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11468800/javafx2-closing-a-stage-substage-from-within-itself)

Comment: Can you explain a bit more what this is supposed to do? Calling `stage.close()` will **not** invoke the `onCloseRequest()` handler. It's not clear if that's what you intend. If you want an event handler that is invoked no matter how the window is closed, you should use `stage.setOnHidden()`.